# Kinda surreal sci-fi animated movie from before 1990 on an alien planet, maybe astronauts

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I watched an animated sci-fi movie during the early 90s, I have flashes in my mind but could not identify it for years and years.

Searching around by myself, I found some stuff with a bit similar style but not quite the same:

- *Fantastic Planet* (*La Planete Sauvage* 1973)
- *Time Masters* (*Le Maitres du Temps* 1983)

Those come close to it. Maybe *Time Masters* is closest. But the movie I remember is more surreal, more stylized, and MAYBE has no voice over.

I remember a scene where 3 people were running away from some danger, inside a giant subterranean cavern (probably an alien planet) full of lava, and one of them died in the lava. The other two, a man and a woman, kept going, but before reaching the exit something bad happened, and one of them died (maybe by gunshot, and I can't recall who, maybe one of them was not really a friend to the other but a traitor).

Also I remember someone melting or fusing into the lava, or fusing to someone else, no idea.

I remember white, faceless beings too, and those are present in *Time Masters*, so maybe some other movie that copied it?

I believe it was not in English language (title and maybe some more stuff during the movie). I mentioned below "no voice over" but maybe there were a few dialogues? The memories are too hazy, sorry!

If any of you have watched the movie Krull, the scene

> where the guy who can see the future dies

has a similar general atmosphere to the scene I mentioned on the animation where one of the two people die escaping from the cave..

Comment: "White, faceless beings" were the same (angel-like), or there was some difference ?

Comment: Starchaser: The Legend of Orin is a 1985 animated dark sci-fi fantasy film.  The beginning has its Luke Skywalker and his female friend try to escape the mine the are slaves in but she dies.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes me think of two distinctly different animated feature films. Neither of which is an EXACT match though.

Both "Les Maîtres du Temps" and "La Planète Sauvage" were directed by Rene Laloux who worked together with an artist who designed the overall visual concepts for the movie. So each film looked slightly different from the other.

He made a third animated feature film called "Gandahar" (1987). This time based on the design of artist Caza (of comic book magazine Metal Hurlant/Heavy Metal magazine fame). Maybe this is the film you're looking for. It is surreal, that's for sure.

It takes place on a peaceful planet where the humans have formed a relationship with nature where human technology is derived from animals in a sort of symbiotic manner. Suddenly the world is threatened by an ever growing army of mechanical men in faceless shiny black stormtrooper esque armor. They fire lazerbeams from their finger tips that turn humans into stone. The stone figures are then collected in a huge tank. The metal men's actions come from them having misinterpreted the words of a divine super-intelligent giant sea creature that looks like an amoeba. The Hero and Heroine follow the metal men until they find the sea creature and get absorbed by it.

or

Maybe the movie you're looking for is Ralph Bakshi's "Fire And Ice" (1983).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_Ice_(1983_film)#/media/File:Fire_and_Ice_1983_poster.png

It's a sword and sorcery fantasy film and the ending involves streams of lava. It's not really surreal, but it has long episodes without any dialogue. Character design was done by legendary fantasy artist Frank Frazetta. Comic book writers Gerry Conway and Roy Thomas provided the original screenplay.

The Story is about a world divided, into one hot and one cold side, as a result of the world being out of balance. The cold is mastered by a troubled young magician prince and his domineering queen mother who is also a magic user. A girl from the other side is abducted to be the wife of the magician, as ordered by the queen. A young barbarian warrior goes out alone to rescue the young woman and along the way befriends an oddly dressed tracker/ranger (based on Frazetta's Jaguar God character) out to destroy the evil magician queen.

Fire and Ice trailer - YouTube

Comment: It'd better to edit this answer to focus on a single title (whichever one you think is most likely to be correct), and add separate answers for any other titles you think might be the one the OP was looking for.